# How to calculate voltages in op-amp circuits?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current-source, inverting-amplifier

I don't know how to solve the following problems; I don't even know what the best way to start solving them is.

Can someone help me with the calculation steps so I can then try to solve them on my own?

The task is to calculate the voltages *v<sub>N</sub>*, *v<sub>P</sub>* and *v<sub>O</sub>* in figure 6.11.

This is an ideal op-amp which means that no current is flowing into the input ports. But which current flows through the 1 kΩ resistance?

Can I use a voltage divider here?

$$v_N = \frac{v_O \times 1\text{ k}\Omega}{1\text{ k}\Omega + 3\text{ k}\Omega}$$

[image]

Comment: "This is an ideal op-amp which means that no current is flowing into the input ports." - as a hint (since worked solutions/full answers to HW questions are discouraged here) - what *other* things do you know about the op amp's voltage and current? Are there any mathematical facts (like \$I_+ = I_- = 0\$ which you stated already) that you can definitively state just knowing that the op amp is ideal? and if so, does that yield an answer when you combine them with KCL/KVL (or other solving techniques) that generate mathematical equations/facts about the remainder of the circuit?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. You need to make an effort to solve this yourself. Show us your work, then ask a specific question.

Comment: I dont understand where the current of 1mA is flowing

Comment: You urgently need to study and understand the basic theory of OPAMPs. There are plenty of resources online to do so. We will not solve homework for you. You MUST show some progress otherwise your question will be removed sooner or later.  What is the relationship between the voltages V+ and V-? What is the ideal input current on each terminal?

Comment: Consider the relationship between Vn and Vp for an ideal op-amp (infinite gain and no limit to output voltage).

Answer (score -1):

The usual assumption in such questions is that negative feedback causes the op-amp to adjust its output \$v_O\$ to whatever potential is necessary to equalise the potential of its two inputs:

$$ v_P = v_N $$

You may also consider the op-amp's output to be an independent voltage source, meaning that the entire circuit can be analysed as if the op-amp weren't even there. The question can be partially rewritten as "what output \$v_O\$ must the op-amp produce to satisfy the condition \$ v_P = v_N \$?":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcEVgs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Normally this network would not have a solution, since any application of nodal or mesh analysis would yield fewer independent simultaneous equations than there are unknown terms. However, we have the condition that \$v_N = v_P\$, which is the last piece of the puzzle. You can apply Kirchhoff's and Ohm's laws as you would for any such network, in some nodal or mesh analysis, knowing that the potential difference across the current source I5 is zero.

Here's my approach. Remembering that \$v_P = v_N\$, it's clear that \$v_1 = v_3\$ and \$v_2 = v_4\$, which simplifies things considerably:

$$
\begin{aligned}
v_1 &= v_3 = i_1R_1 = i_3R_3 \\ \\
i_3 &= i_1\frac{R_1}{R_3}
\end{aligned}
$$

Similarly:

$$
\begin{aligned}
v_2 &= v_4 = i_2R_2 = i_4R_4 \\ \\
i_4 &= i_2\frac{R_2}{R_4} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

KCL:

$$
\begin{aligned}
i_1 &= i_2 - i_5 \\ \\
&= i_2 - 1 \text{mA} \\ \\
i_4 &= i_3 - i_5 \\ \\
i_2\frac{R_2}{R_4} &= i_1\frac{R_1}{R_3} - 1 \text{mA} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

KVL:

$$
\begin{aligned}
v_O &= i_1R_1 + i_2R_2 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we have three independent equations in terms of three unknowns \$i_1\$, \$i_2\$ and \$v_O\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
i_1 &= i_2 - 1 \text{mA} \\ \\
i_2\frac{R_2}{R_4} &= i_1\frac{R_1}{R_3} - 1 \text{mA} \\ \\
v_O &= i_1R_1 + i_2R_2 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

After solving those, you can proceed to find any potential or current anywhere in the system.